# Dynamicaly display selected option from Django form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Django html form like this:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Task</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="task_name" id="task_name" onchange="show()">
                <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
                {% for item in tasks %}
                    <option>{{item.task_name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5 submit">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" name="save">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

where items contains dictionary data.

I need to dynamically create few lines of html code that contain data for selected item.

For now I can only get selected text value [I'm new in jQuery]. But it is not displayed dynamically after selection.

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function show(){
        var txt = $("#task_name").val();
        $('#txt_name').val(txt);
    });
</script>
```

destination:

```
<p id="txt_name"/>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to add a event listener for onChange of your select input.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal i have try this but is not working. I get selected text only after submitting form.

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: How is this a Python/Django question actually ??? (tags removed).

Answer (score 2):

You need an event handler.

Try:

```
$(function(){
    $("#task_name").on("change",function(){
      $('#txt_name').val($(this).val());
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thank You :). Do you know how to get data from selected item?

Comment: You could store additional data for each option in some data- attributes and access it with `.data()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an event handler for onChange event of your select input. Also to set `text` of a `<p>` tag you need to call the method `text`.
Here is a working example:

```js
// Define an event handler, don't call it yet
function show(){
  var txt = $("#task_name").val();
  console.log(txt);  // just to see when method runs, can remove on production
  $('#txt_name').text(txt);  // you need to call text to set text of <p>
}

$("#task_name").on("change", show);  // register an event handler for onChange of your select input
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="task_name" id="task_name">
  <option value="" hidden>Select</option>
  <option value="task1">task1</option>
  <option value="task2">task2</option>
  <option value="task3">task3</option>
</select>
<p id="txt_name"/>
```

Comment: Thank You :). Do you know how to get data from selected item?

Comment: what data. You already have the value of selected option in `var txt = $("#task_name").val();`

Comment: but this is only selected value. I need in next step to get data from selected dictionary item.

Comment: too complicated to do in django template. Switch to Django API + seperate js frontend (React, Angular, etc.) if you have that complex requirements. If you use Django templates you will have to dump the `tasks` list as json, and save it as js array in your template. Then you will create options using js instead of using `for` loop in Django template. Also may open your website for security vulnerabilities depending on where `tasks` is coming from.